# TelemetryConfiguration configuration shows Sonar issue when I use with it's instance

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, azure-sdk-.net

When I use the `TelemetryConfiguration` instance for passing configuration.It throws a sonar issue like

```
'TelemetryConfiguration.TelemetryConfiguration(string)' is obsolete: 'InstrumentationKey based global ingestion is being deprecated. Use the default constructor and manually set TelemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString. See https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2560 for more details.' [SofyUtilCommon]csharp(CS0618)
```

My code :

```
public class AppInsightsService
{
     public static string InstrumentationKey => 
     AppSettings.ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey;

    /// <summary>The TelemetryConfiguration for application</summary>
    public static TelemetryConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get => configuration ??= new TelemetryConfiguration(InstrumentationKey);
        set => configuration = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? how to fix this error?

Comment: yes. How we can remove this sonar error for line 
`get => configuration ??= new TelemetryConfiguration(InstrumentationKey);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried below solution and it works for me and also sonar is not showing any error.

```
public static string InstrumentationKey => AppSettings.ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey;
public static TelemetryConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get {
          configuration ??= new TelemetryConfiguration();
          configuration.ConnectionString = $"InstrumentationKey={InstrumentationKey}";
          return configuration;
        } 
        set => configuration = value;
    }
```